SLF4J and Java 11 error while spark version upgrade
I am facing this error
"SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_11"
I am upgrading the spark version from 1.6 to 3.5.1. I have not used slf4j in my entire code. Instead I am using log4j(version 1.2.17) and Java version 8 and maven 3.9.5.
NOTE. The code is being run in my local
I want to run the code on 3.5.x

"I have not used slf4j in my entire code." - But one of the dependencies uses it!  (And if you are still using log4j 1.2.17, there are a bunch of vulnerabilities that you need to consider; see https://security.snyk.io/package/maven/log4j:log4j/1.2.17)

I have removed that log4j dependency and added slf4j. But that Java11 error still persists. I have check the entire dependency tree but couldn't find anything

Please show us the complete exception stacktrace.
